# if div has class remove the class and add it to its parent

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have

```
<div class="image-mask">
    <img class="alignright" src="image.png" />
</div>
```

and I would like to use jQuery to move the class from the image to the parent div.

Thanks very much!!

Comment: Just a picky note if you're interested: 
You shouldn't use class-names like `alignright` as it's not semantic to what the image represents / leave that for the CSS.  The class should be representative of your content and it's relationship to other content - avoid classnames like `center`, `alignleft`, `bigfont` because they aren't semantic. This might point you in the right direction: http://html5doctor.com/lets-talk-about-semantics/

Comment: Just to clarify, that's wordpress's class for aligning images :) I am picky as Hell with what I name :D Thanks for the reminder!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should work:

```
 $('.alignright').removeClass('alignright').parent().addClass('alignright');
```

Comment: BOOM! Thanks! just waiting for the time to be able to click the check!